# Serial connection to Cisco C40 not taking input

Tags: putty, administrator, serial-port, hyperterminal

I have a cisco c40 video codec that is not accepting the admin credentials that I established for it over SSH/HTTPS. I suspect that the config file is corrupt as there are other erroneous behaviors in the settings regarding DHCP and gatekeeper settings.

I have seen several methods for resolving this via a serial connection. Each involves connecting via 38400, 8, N, 1 and either breaking the boot sequence (b or c during boot) and removing the config file OR logging in within 1 minute of boot with the user 'pwrec' to reset the root login.

The problem I am having - using both hyperterminal and Putty - is that neither accepts any input from terminal at any point during the connection. So I can't break the boot sequence OR enter login information.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to force commands using a different sequence of key presses?

EDIT: I have also read the [support documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/telepresence/endpoint/codec-c-series/tc4/api_reference_guide/codec-c60-c40_api_reference_guide_tc41.pdf) for the unit and I am using a straight through serial cable for the connection from BOTH a USB-Serial adapter and a native serial port.

Comment: By accept do you mean it rejects the input or simply doesn't register you have provided ANY input, the later sounds like, your not connecting to anything.

Comment: It does not register input. I am connected - as I can clearly read and observe the boot sequence and login prompts that appear in the terminal window - as well as the commands to break the boot sequence.

Comment: So you are being sent data.  You just can't send data yourself. Is that correct?

Comment: Affirmative - I'm only getting output.